# If gypsum turns into plaster around 210 F, is there any natural plaster deposits or formations out there?

Tags: rocks, water

For a while I have been working with gypsum I mined from a site in Utah, and I realized how low the temperature is to turn it into plaster, so I was wandering; has there ever been any cases of large deposits of gypsum being naturally heated into plaster and coming in contact with water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Water is removed from gypsum hydrate about 300 F+ making it dry powder gypsum. Water is added to gypsum to make "plaster of Paris" , no particular temperature is involved. Not sure it answers the question , but gypsum commonly deposits in oil production tubing. The produced oil/water/gas  mix cools as it comes up the well tubing and deposits in the tubing,; very difficult to prevent or remove.

Comment: Oh I have made plaster from raw gypsum crystals before around 250 F, so I am going to take it there is no cases of natural plaster casts out there.